# Metadata Rejection; Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, metadata

My iOS App received a metadata rejection because I made a mistake in the review information for In App Purchases. Made the necessary correction and submitted an appeal to the App Review board. Has been a week but still no response. What is the correct course of action to get the app passed through the review? Should I re-submit the build using "Submit for review" button?

Comment: Did you manage to get approval?

Comment: Yes..I did...After 20 days.....Didn't have to make any changes in the app though.

Comment: Wow! 20 days. Could’ve been worse. I think there is no rational explanation behind this.

Comment: Ok mine got approved after 3 days. So I have no idea what the criteria is.

Comment: Depends on the number of In App Purchases, Metadata Rejections of your app. Mine had three In App Purchases and thats probably what took so long. Meta data rejections can really stop your app for weeks.

Comment: I had gotten a long list of Metadata rejection with this. I had 1 IAP, but I also have Ads in my app via AdMob. The only change I did before re-submitting was to change the Admob setting to exclude some Sensitive, and Gambling Ads. I am not really sure if this was exactly the reason but it looks like it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Submit a New Binary

You have the following options:

- Submit a new binary for review with the corrected meta-data;
- Wait for the appeal; this could take a week or more;
- Contact [Apple Developer directly](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and ask for an update.

Anecdotally, submitting a new binary for review tends to be the fastest approach.

Given the application was rejected for a valid reason you agree with, there is nothing to appeal. The appeal can only fail. Resubmit the application with the corrected In-App Purchase meta-data.

Comment: It's just an issue with the metadata. Are you sure that submitting a new binary is the best option? Because the binary I would upload would not have any code changes I guess.

Comment: Along with the rejection, they sent a message which states that: Before we can continue with our review, please confirm that this app does not violate any of the above guidelines. You may reply to this message in Resolution Center or the App Review Information section in iTunes Connect to verify this app’s compliance. 
Given the tendency for apps of this type to violate the aforementioned guidelines, this review will take additional time. Should you choose to resubmit this app without confirming this app’s compliance, the next submission of this app will still require a longer review time.

Comment: If you know a resubmitted application will comply, resubmit. Otherwise I would wait. You can always phone Apple and ask. Ultimately, only Apple can provide an answer.

Comment: how to solve out metadata error let me know any one know y

Comment: I’ve gotten the same rejection today. My app has been happily live for months with multiple updates. My last update was a bug fix. It’s quite bizarre that they just gave this laundry list of things and I think it’s a 2018 thing. My guess is that they are testing a new Review Bot which has some pre configured criterias. What was ok for a human to approve is not ok for the bot. And then it would just push the review down the queue for an actual human to review. This is plain frustrating.